# React throws CORs errors when moving recaptch ready callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I have a React app created with create-react-app. I am putting reCaptcha on it and put in the below and all is great. Token comes back and I can nest a fetch and move on with my life.

```
componentDidMount(){
  if(!this.state.isRecaptchaReady){
       window.grecaptcha.ready(function(){
         window.grecaptcha.execute('id', {action: 'homepage'})
        .then(//...)
    });
  } 
}
```

Except I cannot because I know there has to be a better way. I want to get the token and store it and then call a function off of that rather then nesting so deep I cannot get `this` to save my life (I mean I could but don't want to with a bunch of binds).

```
requestRecaptchToken = () => {
    console.log(window.grecaptcha);
    //const tokenPromise = window.grecaptcha.execute('id', {action: 'homepage'});
  }

  handleRecaptchToken = data => {
    const { modal } = this.state;
    modal.recaptcha = JSON.parse(data);
    this.setState({modal});
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    if(!this.state.isRecaptchaReady){
      window.grecaptcha.ready(this.handleRecaptchReady());
    } 
  }

componentDidUpdate(){
  if(this.state.isRecaptchaReady){
    this.requestRecaptchToken();
  }
}
```

This line

```
const tokenPromise = window.grecaptcha.execute('id', {action: 'homepage'});
```

outside of

```
window.grecaptcha.ready()
```

blows up with

> Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html for more information.

Issue is it makes no sense and I read some WebPack eval stuff but that seems a bit above my learning curve at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The message that React was throwing was mostly because I was not catching errors and it had no idea where to look. I still have no idea why calling `execute` outside of `ready` behaves erroneously but I think there is race condition between calling methods, the renders and what react has access to. This is strictly speculation I have no idea how to prove it yet.

I did however solve the issue after taking a step back and thinking about my goal. Instead of breaking this out into multiple method (my java brain got in the way) I simply used arrow function for their to bind `this` scoping to the component.

```
try {
  window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    window.grecaptcha.execute(process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_ID).then(data => {
      this.handleRecaptchToken(data);
    });
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log("reCaptcha token load error: " + e);
}
```

That with the fact that `setState` can take an optional callback method as a second parameter allows for `handleRecaptchToken` to fetch the data once the token data is complete.

```
handleRecaptchToken = data => {
  this.setState({"recaptchaToken" : data}, this.fetchRecaptchaData);
}
```

`fetchRecaptchaData` then does an api call to my server to get the google data and update the state once more.